# How to make specific lists value (tcl)

Tags: list, tcl

I want to make specific repetitive lists.
XA0 XB0 XC0 XD0 XD1 XC1 XB1 XA1 XA2 XB2 XC2 XD2 XD3 XC3 XB3 XA3.....
As you see, A-B-C-D-D-C-B-A ... what is repetitive patterns & counts are also expanded.

Experts! Please help me!!

Comment: What do you start with? Otherwise, is there any reason why you don't want to create the list manually?

Comment: There are not some input, but know counts of loop. And this counts are variable. So it doesn't mean to make manually.

Comment: Can you provide a few different inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks for your comment . As we know, input numbers are 640. I want to get result list. This list is included XA0 XB0 XC0 XD0 XD1 XC1 XB1 XA1 XA2 XB2 XC2 XD2 XD3 XC3 XB3 XA3 ....  set aa "" for {set i 0} {$i < 640} {incr $i} { ....} maybe i think it need to use lappend and so on.

Answer (score 0):

OK, flipping the pattern makes this a little trickier. But we have `lreverse` so it's not too difficult; we just need to flip the list of letters after each round of iterating through it.

```
set resultList {}
set letters {A B C D}
for {set i 0} {$i <= 3} {incr i} {
    foreach ch $letters {
        lappend resultList "X${ch}${i}"
    }
    set letters [lreverse $letters]
}
puts $resultList
# XA0 XB0 XC0 XD0 XD1 XC1 XB1 XA1 XA2 XB2 XC2 XD2 XD3 XC3 XB3 XA3
```

Comment: If you want a limit bigger than 3, I believe you can find where to alter that code…

Comment: I didn't know 'lreverse'. I'll try to apply this to my work later. Thanks a lot!